# How to get a specific tag from a div class with this html page?

Tags: android, dom, jsoup

I am trying to retrieve the image url in from this [html page](http://ds.gamespy.com/nintendo-3ds/brunswick-pro-bowling/)

The image is inside of the editions box on the webpage. How would i go about getting it using the JSoup selector method.

Such as

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Element png  = doc.select(//What would the tag be?);
```

I have an idea of how to set it up, just not how to retrieve the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doc.select("div.box-art").select("img").attr("abs:src"));

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) it looks like doc.select(".box-art img") should do the trick. (Select an img element which is the child of an element of class box-art.) Note that this could get you multiple imgs, (if JSoup supports that).

Comment: According to the [docs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#attr(java.lang.String)) you should be able to call attr() on the return value of select() (an object of class Elements) to get the value of an attribute in the first element which has that attribute. I.e. call attr("abs:src") like the answer below says.